# Probability that a triangle can be solved

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Consider a triangle $ABC$ with it's angles $\alpha, \beta , \theta$. $A$ is opposite $\alpha$, $B$ is opposite $\beta$ and $C$ is opposite $\theta$. A triangle is considered solvable if you have two angles and a side *not* between them, two angles, and a side in between, two sides and an angle between them, or three sides.

We are given *three*  random values in different positions on either $A,B,C,\alpha, \beta, \theta$. These are values from a certain true triangle.

What is the probability that:

- A single triangle is solvable

What is the probability that for $N$ triangles:

- At least half of them can be solved
- At least a third of them can be solved
- All of them can be solved
- None of them can be solved

I would like these probabilities to be in fractions.

Comment: It isn't mentioned anywhere so I ask: is each combination of the three given values equally likely?

Comment: @WaveX yes Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${6\choose3}=20$ different data triples that can be formed from $a$, $b$, $c$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. The triples that cannot be "solved" are of the form $(a,b,\alpha)$ (six of these), and $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.

It follows that a random triple is "solvable" with probability $p={13\over20}$. The probability that all of $N$ independently chosen triples are solvable is $p^N$, and the probability that none of the $N$ can be solved is $(1-p)^N$. The two remaining bullets lead to sums involving binomial coefficients and powers of $p$, resp., $1-p$.

As your username says: This was really simple.